# Increasing the volume of an HID device using feature reports

Tags: usb, google-chrome-app, chromium, hid

**What hex code do I need to send to the device (and what report index) to trigger a volume change?**

I'm trying to use HID feature reports to increase the volume of a [Jabra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabra_(headset)) 410 headset. The Jabra provides the following interface and report description:

https://pastebin.com/ES8ivMym

```
Report Descriptor: (length is 273)
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x0c ] 12
                        Consumer
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Consumer Control
        Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Application
        Item(Global): Report ID, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x0c ] 12
                        Consumer
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0xea ] 234
                        Volume Decrement
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0xe9 ] 233
                        Volume Increment
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0xe2 ] 226
                        Mute
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x03 ] 3
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x05 ] 5
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Constant Array Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x00 0xff ] 65280
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        (null)
        Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Application
        Item(Global): Report ID, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x20 ] 32
        Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x02 0x01 ] 258
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Buffered Bytes
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x20 ] 32
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 0x01 ] 258
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Buffered Bytes
        Item(Global): Report ID, data= [ 0x04 ] 4
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x30 0xff ] 65328
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x20 ] 32
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x97 ] 151
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x2b ] 43
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x03 ] 3
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x23 ] 35
                        Constant Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        No_Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x2f ] 47
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x21 ] 33
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x24 ] 36
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0xfd 0xff ] 65533
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x04 ] 4
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x07 ] 7
                        Constant Variable Relative No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Constant Array Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0xff 0xff ] 65535
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Main  ): Feature, data= [ 0x22 ] 34
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        No_Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x07 ] 7
        Item(Main  ): Feature, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Constant Array Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x40 0xff ] 65344
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x17 ] 23
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x1e ] 30
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x18 ] 24
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x20 ] 32
                        (null)
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x21 ] 33
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x06 ] 6
        Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x22 ] 34
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        No_Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x30 0xff ] 65328
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x9e ] 158
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x22 ] 34
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        No_Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
        Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Constant Array Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x0b ] 11
                        Telephony
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x05 ] 5
                        Headset
        Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Application
        Item(Global): Report ID, data= [ 0x03 ] 3
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x0b ] 11
                        Telephony
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x20 ] 32
                        Hook Switch
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x97 ] 151
                        Line Busy Tone
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x2b ] 43
                        Speaker Phone
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x03 ] 3
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x23 ] 35
                        Constant Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        No_Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x2f ] 47
                        Phone Mute
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x21 ] 33
                        Flash
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x24 ] 36
                        Redial
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x03 ] 3
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x07 ] 7
                        Constant Variable Relative No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x07 ] 7
                        Programmable Button
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
                        Buttons
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Button 1 (Primary)
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
        Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Constant Array Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
                        LEDs
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x17 ] 23
                        Off-Hook
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x1e ] 30
                        Speaker
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
                        Mute
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x18 ] 24
                        Ring
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x20 ] 32
                        Hold
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x21 ] 33
                        Microphone
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x06 ] 6
        Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x22 ] 34
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        No_Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x0b ] 11
                        Telephony
        Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
        Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x9e ] 158
                        (null)
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x22 ] 34
                        Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        No_Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
        Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x09 ] 9
        Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                        Constant Array Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                        Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
        Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
```

I have successfully used feature report #3 to interact with the device, including the manipulation of some LEDs and call states. However, no combination of data changes the volume, and I get no response whatsoever when interacting with feature report #1, which should be responsible for volume if I'm reading the report properly.

For example, sending a hex value of 05 (as in 00000101) to page #3 results in the device going to a muted state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decoded the report descriptor and it appears that the volume increment/decrement reports are sent from the device (headset) to the host (PC or whatever) using an *input* report, not a *feature* report. That is, the device tells the host to increment/decrement the volume - not the other way around.

BTW, I only see one feature report defined and it uses REPORT_ID 0x04.

Specifically, the input report with REPORT_ID 0x01 is used for volume control:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Consumer Device Page inputReport 01 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x01 (1)
                                                     // Collection: ConsumerControl
  uint8_t  CD_ConsumerControlVolumeDecrement : 1;    // Usage 0x000C00EA: Volume Decrement, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  CD_ConsumerControlVolumeIncrement : 1;    // Usage 0x000C00E9: Volume Increment, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  CD_ConsumerControlMute : 1;               // Usage 0x000C00E2: Mute, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} inputReport01_t;
```

The full decoded report descriptor is shown below...

```
hidrdd git:master ❯ rexx rd.rex --dump -dsa samples/headset-jabra410.rd

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Report descriptor data in hex (length 273 bytes)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// 050C0901 A1018501 050C1500 250109EA 09E909E2 75019503 81027501 95058101
// C00600FF 0901A101 85020901 150026FF 00750895 20920201 09011500 26FF0075
// 08952082 02018504 0630FF15 00250109 20099709 2B750195 03812309 2F092109
// 240AFDFF 75019504 81077501 95098101 0AFFFF75 019501B1 22750195 07B10106
// 40FF1500 25010917 091E0909 09180920 09217501 95069122 0630FF15 00250109
// 9E750195 01912275 01950991 01C0050B 0905A101 8503050B 15002501 09200997
// 092B7501 95038123 092F0921 09247501 95038107 09070509 09017501 95018102
// 95098101 05081500 25010917 091E0909 09180920 09217501 95069122 050B1500
// 2501099E 75019501 91227501 95099101 C0


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 0C        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000C Consumer Device Page
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C0001 Consumer Control (CA=Application Collection)
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00000001 Application (Usage=0x000C0001: Page=Consumer Device Page, Usage=Consumer Control, Type=CA)
85 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x01 (1)
05 0C          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000C Consumer Device Page <-- Redundant: USAGE_PAGE is already 0x000C
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)
09 EA          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C00EA Volume Decrement (RTC=Re-trigger Control)
09 E9          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C00E9 Volume Increment (RTC=Re-trigger Control)
09 E2          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C00E2 Mute (OOC=On/Off Control)
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field
95 03          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 05          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields
81 01          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000001 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Consumer Device Page inputReport 01 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x01 (1)
                                                     // Collection: ConsumerControl
  uint8_t  CD_ConsumerControlVolumeDecrement : 1;    // Usage 0x000C00EA: Volume Decrement, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  CD_ConsumerControlVolumeIncrement : 1;    // Usage 0x000C00E9: Volume Increment, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  CD_ConsumerControlMute : 1;               // Usage 0x000C00E2: Mute, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} inputReport01_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
06 00FF      (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF00 Vendor-defined
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00000001 Application (Usage=0xFF000001: Page=Vendor-defined, Usage=, Type=)
85 02          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x02 (2)
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF00        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255)
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field
95 20          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x20 (32) Number of fields
92 0201        (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000102 (32 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 1=Buffer
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF000001 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF00        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 255
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 8
95 20          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x20 (32) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 32
82 0201        (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000102 (32 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 1=Buffer
85 04          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x04 (4)
06 30FF        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF30 Vendor-defined
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)
09 20          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF300020 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 97          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF300097 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 2B          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF30002B <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field
95 03          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields
81 23          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000023 (3 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 1=NoPrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
09 2F          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF30002F <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 21          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF300021 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 24          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF300024 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
0A FDFF        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF30FFFD <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 04          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x04 (4) Number of fields
81 07          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000007 (4 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 09          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x09 (9) Number of fields
81 01          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000001 (9 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute
0A FFFF        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF30FFFF <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields
B1 22          (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000022 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 1=NoPrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 07          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x07 (7) Number of fields
B1 01          (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000001 (7 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
06 40FF        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF40 Vendor-defined
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 1
09 17          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF400017 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 1E          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF40001E <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 09          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF400009 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 18          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF400018 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 20          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF400020 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
09 21          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF400021 <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 06          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x06 (6) Number of fields
91 22          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000022 (6 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 1=NoPrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
06 30FF        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0xFF30 Vendor-defined
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 1
09 9E          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0xFF30009E <-- Warning: Undocumented usage
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields
91 22          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000022 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 1=NoPrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 09          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x09 (9) Number of fields
91 01          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000001 (9 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined featureReport 04 (Device <-> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x04 (4)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefinedFFFF : 1;                // Usage 0xFF30FFFF: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} featureReport04_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined inputReport 02 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x02 (2)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0001[32];                // Usage 0xFF000001: , Value = 0 to 255
} inputReport02_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined inputReport 04 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x04 (4)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0020 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF300020: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0097 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF300097: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined002B : 1;                // Usage 0xFF30002B: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined002F : 1;                // Usage 0xFF30002F: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0021 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF300021: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0024 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF300024: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefinedFFFD : 1;                // Usage 0xFF30FFFD: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} inputReport04_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined outputReport 02 (Device <-- Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x02 (2)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0001[32];                // Usage 0xFF000001: , Value = 0 to 255
} outputReport02_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vendor-defined outputReport 04 (Device <-- Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x04 (4)
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0017 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF400017: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined001E : 1;                // Usage 0xFF40001E: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0009 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF400009: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0018 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF400018: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0020 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF400020: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined0021 : 1;                // Usage 0xFF400021: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  VEN_VendorDefined009E : 1;                // Usage 0xFF30009E: , Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} outputReport04_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 0B        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000B Telephony Device Page
09 05        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B0005 Headset (CL=Logical Collection)
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00000001 Application (Usage=0x000B0005: Page=Telephony Device Page, Usage=Headset, Type=CL) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CA (Application)
85 03          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x03 (3)
05 0B          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000B Telephony Device Page <-- Redundant: USAGE_PAGE is already 0x000B
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 1
09 20          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B0020 Hook Switch (OOC=On/Off Control)
09 97          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B0097 Line Busy Tone (MC=Momentary Control)
09 2B          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B002B Speaker Phone (OOC=On/Off Control)
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 03          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields
81 23          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000023 (3 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 1=NoPrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
09 2F          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B002F Phone Mute (OOC=On/Off Control)
09 21          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B0021 Flash (MC=Momentary Control)
09 24          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B0024 Redial (OSC=One Shot Control)
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 03          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 3
81 07          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000007 (3 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
09 07          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B0007 Programmable Button (NAry=Named Array)
05 09          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot)
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
95 09          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x09 (9) Number of fields
81 01          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000001 (9 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute
05 08          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0008 LED Indicator Page
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 1
09 17          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00080017 Off-Hook (OOC=On/Off Control)
09 1E          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x0008001E Speaker (OOC=On/Off Control)
09 09          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00080009 Mute (OOC=On/Off Control)
09 18          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00080018 Ring (OOC=On/Off Control)
09 20          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00080020 Hold (OOC=On/Off Control)
09 21          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00080021 Microphone (OOC=On/Off Control)
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 06          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x06 (6) Number of fields
91 22          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000022 (6 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 1=NoPrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
05 0B          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000B Telephony Device Page
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 1
09 9E          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000B009E Ringer (OOC=On/Off Control)
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields
91 22          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000022 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 1=NoPrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 1
95 09          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x09 (9) Number of fields
91 01          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000001 (9 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Telephony Device Page inputReport 03 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x03 (3)
                                                     // Collection: Headset
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetHookSwitch : 1;                // Usage 0x000B0020: Hook Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetLineBusyTone : 1;              // Usage 0x000B0097: Line Busy Tone, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetSpeakerPhone : 1;              // Usage 0x000B002B: Speaker Phone, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetPhoneMute : 1;                 // Usage 0x000B002F: Phone Mute, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetFlash : 1;                     // Usage 0x000B0021: Flash, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetRedial : 1;                    // Usage 0x000B0024: Redial, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetProgrammableButton : 1;        // Usage 0x000B0007: Programmable Button, Value = 0 to 1
                                                     // Usage 0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) Value = 0 to 1 <-- Ignored: REPORT_COUNT (1) is too small
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} inputReport03_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// LED Indicator Page outputReport 03 (Device <-- Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x03 (3)
                                                     // Collection: Headset
  uint8_t  LED_HeadsetOffHook : 1;                   // Usage 0x00080017: Off-Hook, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  LED_HeadsetSpeaker : 1;                   // Usage 0x0008001E: Speaker, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  LED_HeadsetMute : 1;                      // Usage 0x00080009: Mute, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  LED_HeadsetRing : 1;                      // Usage 0x00080018: Ring, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  LED_HeadsetHold : 1;                      // Usage 0x00080020: Hold, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  LED_HeadsetMicrophone : 1;                // Usage 0x00080021: Microphone, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  TEL_HeadsetRinger : 1;                    // Usage 0x000B009E: Ringer, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
} outputReport03_t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response aja. I'm a bit confused since when I connect the Jabra 410 to my macbook and press the volume down button on the macbook, the Jabra reflects that volume change. Are you saying the HID report does not indicate any means of setting the volume through the HID interface?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think - but it's hard to be 100% certain when there are vendor defined usages involved. For example, report id 0x02 seems to be for digitized audio in 32-byte packets (I can't really tell because it is vendor defined), but who knows whether each packet also contains a header allowing control data to flow. You may have to snoop the traffic with wireshark or similar to find out.

Comment: Thanks again for the response, aja. If you have a moment, the Jabra spec describes setting the volume from the host, but I cannot understand which interface they are suggesting I use. http://developer.jabra.com/site/global/sdks/web/documentation/index.gsp#TOC24

Comment: @PeterMortensen Do you mean the decoded source? It wasn't copied, but rather was generated by some software I wrote I while back that decodes HID report descriptors. See https://github.com/abend0c1/hidrdd